# Smarter way for a drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,anysize}
\marginsize{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
\definecolor{forest}{RGB}{34,139,34}
\definecolor{rot}{RGB}{220,20,60}
\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{0,191,255}
\definecolor{mitter}{RGB}{25,25,112}
\definecolor{ora}{RGB}{255,69,0}
\newcommand{\nice}[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.2]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\w}{360/#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\q}{360-\w}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\f}{#1/10}
%       \pgfmathsetmacro{\f}{17}
            \foreach \x in {0,\w,...,\q}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\sch}{#2*\x+\w}
                \draw[#3] (\x:\f) -- (\sch:\f);
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{rl}
           \nice{200}{2}{orange!60!yellow} & \nice{200}{3}{forest} \\
           \nice{200}{4}{rot} & \nice{200}{5}{blau} \\
           \nice{200}{5}{mitter} & \nice{200}{6}{ora}
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: shot]

[image: shot]

[image: shot]

My question is: Is there a smarter way to draw something like this? The computation doesn't take long, but I'm sure there is a better way to do this …

---

An [animated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go0S1.jpg) `.gif` (too large for the embedded imgur service). Here is [another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3z4Q.jpg) one.

Comment: +1 for the code, I do not have a superior knowledge to improve what you have done...

Comment: The only obvious change that I can think of would be to make it a `pic` so that it can be used inside a `tikzpicture` and the styles would then be more flexible.

Comment: @Loop_Space: Could you please post a MWE? I think I know what you're talking about …

Comment: One thing you could do (which won't make you very popular with those who try to understand how your magic works ;-) is to eliminate all auxiliary macros and just say `\newcommand{\nice}[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.2]
            \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
            {
                \draw[#3] ({((\x-1)/#1)*360}:{#1/10}) -- ({#2*((\x-1)/#1)*360}:{#1/10});
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}`. And if others blame you for that, your could simply respond that every good magician keeps some of her/his secrets. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulations to your spectacular code and results! The IMHO best way to improve your code is to use `pic`s, but this has already been suggested by [Loop Space in his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448986/smarter-way-for-a-drawing#comment1128111_448986). So I post yet another method: `insert path`. This way you can control the line style and so on with the usual options of `\draw`. (Of course, your nice macro allows you also to do this, what follows may just be regarded more Ti*k*Zy.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} % the biggest improvement is "border=3.14mm" ;-)
\definecolor{forest}{RGB}{34,139,34}
\definecolor{rot}{RGB}{220,20,60}
\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{0,191,255}
\definecolor{mitter}{RGB}{25,25,112}
\definecolor{ora}{RGB}{255,69,0}

\tikzset{nice/.style n args={2}{insert path={foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
            {
                 ({((\x-1)/#1)*360}:{#1/10}) -- ({#2*((\x-1)/#1)*360}:{#1/10})
            }}}}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
         \draw[orange!60!yellow,shift={(0,0)},nice={200}{2}];
         \draw[forest,shift={(50,0)},nice={200}{3}];
         \draw[rot,shift={(0,-50)},nice={200}{4}];
         \draw[blau,shift={(50,-50)},nice={200}{5}];
         \draw[mitter,shift={(0,-100)},nice={200}{5}];
         \draw[ora,shift={(50,-100)},nice={200}{6}];
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is essentially the same as yours.

[image]

One difference is that you can place the graphs with Ti*k*Z methods, another one may be that you could decorate the overall path (rather than the individual stretches), but I have not thought of any neat application. So it is unclear if this method is really "better".